# Javascript Event Binding does not work correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a list (navigation menu) with 2 different rows. Each of this row is connected to a diagram. For instance row 1 (Temperature) is connected to Temperature diagram (table1 and table2).

I want the user to decide which table to view by clicking on the navigation menu, and if the person wish to view another table the first diagram has to be closed before the next one comes up. So what do I have to do in javascript (JQuery) in order to do this link up the row1 with the table1 and row2 with table2?

**The problem is that when I click on the next row, nothing happens.**

This index.html:

```
    <!--Link to tables-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/diagram1"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/diagram2"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id = "diagram1"></div> <!--Import html file for chartcontainer-->
    <div id = "diagram2"></div> <!--Import html file for chartcontainer-->
</body>
```

This is javascript inside another file where I have included in index.html.

```
                <ul class="list-group">
                <!--Set this inside a div to individuelly choose-->
                    <div id = "1"><li class="list-group-item">Exhaust Temperature</li></div>
                    <div id = "2"><li class="list-group-item">Cylinder Pressure</li></div>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- end row -->
</div> <!-- container -->

<script>
$(function(){
    $('#1').on('click',function(){
        $('#table1').toggle();
    });

    $('#2').on('click',function(){
        $('#table2').toggle();
    });                     
});
```

Kind regards
Dler H.

Comment: #table1,#table2 where it is?

Comment: id begin with number is not a good idea

Comment: I haven't taken the whole code, but this is from a javascript file where I have included it in index.html. I have changed the numbers to letters in ID. But this still does not solve the problem..

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the other table :

```
$(function(){
    $('#div1').on('click',function(){
        $('#table2').hide();
        $('#table1').toggle();
    });

    $('#div2').on('click',function(){
        $('#table1').hide();
        $('#table2').toggle();
    });
});
```

And change your ids :

```
<div id = "div1"><li class="list-group-item">Exhaust Temperature</li></div>
<div id = "div2"><li class="list-group-item">CylinderPressure</li></div>
```

Comment: it will return error `Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#1' is not a valid selector`

Comment: change your divs id like said above.

Comment: i know that , i said it for you to take care in future , note i am not I'm not the written this question :)

Answer (score 0):

Html id must star with a letter http://www.electrictoolbox.com/valid-characters-html-id-attribute/ so you can't do it `id='1'`